# OCaml - find all possible variations with repetitions

Tags: list, unit-testing, recursion, ocaml

I have ~10 functions that I want to write tests for, they all take two arguments of the same type. I thought I could automate the process a little, creating a list of all possible input classes and just printing all possible variations with repetitions to a text file. My code, howewer, does not quite do the job, only listing variations starting with "a ".

```
let x = ["a "; "b "; "c "; "d "; "e "; "f "; "g "; "h "]
let oc = open_out file

let rec test l1 l2 =
    match l1 with
    |[] -> 0
    |h1::t1 ->
        match l2 with
        |[] -> test t1 l2
        |h2::t2 ->
            fprintf oc "%s\n" (add ^ h1 ^ h2);
            fprintf oc "%s\n" (sub ^ h1 ^ h2);
            fprintf oc "%s\n" (mul ^ h1 ^ h2);
            fprintf oc "%s\n" (div ^ h1 ^ h2);
            test l1 t2;;
test x x;
close_out oc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `|[] -> test t1 l2` you make a recursive call with the empty list for `l2`. I believe you instead want to make the call with the initial value of `l2` (`x` in your example), which then you would need to store somewhere outside of the actual recursion. Something like

```
let test original_l1 original_l2 =
  let rec loop l1 l2 =
    ...
      | [] -> loop l1 original_l2
    ...
    in
  loop original_l1 original_l2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use Monads (see page 5 of [ocaml courses](http://www.dicosmo.org/CourseNotes/pfav/1314/cours7.handout.pdf%22ocaml%20course%22)) :

```
let return x = [x];;
let bind f l = List.fold_right (fun x  acc -> (f x) @ acc) l [];;
let (>>=) l f = bind f l;;
x >>= fun t ->
x >>= fun t' -> 
["add ";"mul ";"sub ";"div "] >>= fun op -> return (op ^ t ^ t') ;;
```

It will return a list representing the cartesian product of x * x * Ops.

May be there is better way to use ocaml Batteries that seems to implement all stuffs needed to do cartesian product.